# need PHP to save data sent as a GET to a file web send

Tags: php, file, web, get, save

I need to send unit ID from Arduino's to web using the form:

```
      http://somdomain.com/path/phpscript.php?ID=5
```

the arduino code is a slam dunk but i need help with the PHP script to accept the server side data and to save the ID number only to a text file named id_file.txt for later parsing.

```
    there are 20 units and i need 1 ID number/line
```

I'm lost to even the structure of the file.

Please Help if possible.

Comment: Thank you all this got me working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Arduino Invoke a page like

```
http://somdomain.com/path/phpscript.php?ID=5
```

Then the phpscript.php will look like this

```
    <?php
    //first line just checks to see if ID is set and if so it'll run the script. This stops the script from running if ID isn't set and someone just randomly comes to the webpage
    if (isset($_GET['ID'])) {

    $id = $_GET['ID'] . "\n"; //I added \n to denote a new line so when you write to this file it'll just append the ID's there
    $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $id); //the second parameter is whatever you want to write to that file
    fclose($myfile);
    }
```

If you wanted to write a new line to the same file that should work

Comment: I ended with a hybrid of both answers .  While i did not need the echo statements, i needed to change the fopen from write to append and it is working great now.   Thank You all

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to write to a file.

```
$filename='myfilename.txt';
if(isset($_GET['ID'])){
   $id= $_GET['ID'];
   if(is_numeric($id)){
      if(file_put_contents($filename,$id,FILE_APPEND)!== FALSE){
          echo "id successfully saved";
      }else{
          echo "there is a error saving your id";
      }
   }
}
```

later  you can read from the file..

```
 $filearray = file($filename,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
 foreach($filearray as $id){
  echo $id;// this print the id's
 }
```